# Setting the content_script matches at runtime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that requires a content_script to add custom controls to a media player. However, I want to allow users to set the domain of the player via an options control panel (for their personal media servers).

It seems like the domain for content scripts has to be set statically in the manifest.json file in the chrome extension. Is there a way to set that programmatically? To achieve something like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<variable_from_config>"],
    "js": ["player.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
]
```

Comment: See the docs on [programmatic injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)

Comment: I added an example. I was hoping to have the manifest set up like above, so I didn't have to inject manually. If there's no simple way to do that, I could just add the script to the page manually.

Comment: The manifest is static so you'll need to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in order to inject your scripts. It shouldn't take too much work if you only need to use 1 url.

Comment: The purpose of the manifest is to determine **at installation time** what the extension can and can't do, so that the user can make an educated decision whether to install it. Making the manifest dynamic would make it much harder to make that determination, which is why it's not allowed. The same consideration applies when uploading the extension to the Chrome Web Store for distribution. The website displays each extension's capabilities, and that feature relies on a static manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new [`contentScripts.register()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contentScripts/register), which does exactly what you want: programmatically registers content scripts.

```js
browser.contentScripts.register({
    matches: ['https://your-dynamic-domain.example.com/*'],
    js: [{file: 'content.js'}]
});
```

This API is only available in Firefox but there's a [Chrome polyfill](https://github.com/fregante/content-scripts-register-polyfill) you can use.

---

For that to work, you'll still need permission to the domain you want to register the script on, so you can use `optional_permissions` in the manifest and `chrome.permissions.request` to let the user add new domains on demand.

I also wrote some tools to further simplify this for you and for the end user, such as 
[`webext-domain-permission-toggle` and `webext-dynamic-content-scripts`](https://github.com/fregante/webext-dynamic-content-scripts/blob/master/how-to-add-github-enterprise-support-to-web-extensions.md). They will also register your scripts in the next browser launches and allow the user the remove the new permissions and scripts.